# finding if a number is a common multiples of some other numbers

Tags: c++, python, c, eclipse, optimization

I want to write a program that calculates if a number is a multiple of some other numbers.
Lets say that i want to check if 25 can be given from a function like 2a+3b+4c=25.Is there any algorithm that can find a b c in order to check if abc are integers?

Comment: Can any of those variables be zero?

Comment: yes i could be any combination

Comment: Wrong site - this isn't really a coding question. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/. Once you've figured out the algorithm and have attempted some code, post here again if you're stuck on a specific code problem.

Comment: In that case, this degenerates into a prime-test, because any non-prime will have a solution.  If you want to generate all possibilities, that's a different story.  And if negatives are allowed, there are infinite solutions.

Comment: sorry a b c are positive integers not negative and it they could be zero

Comment: I was wrong about the prime-test.  *Any* positive integer that is 2 or greater, or 0, has a solution.  I assume therefore that you're asking how to find one or all of the solutions.

Comment: This looks more like a math problem than anything coding-related.

Comment: well lets say that the functios is 5a +8b+ 11c this does not give ane odd or evan algorithm it is more general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For generating all possibilities, a Brute force algorithm will suffice:

Loop over all possible values for `a` and subtract the sum `2a` from 25.  Nest similar loops for `b` using the remainder.  If the remainder after subtracting `3b` is a multiple of 4, then loop over all possible values of `c` and output `a`, `b`, and `c`  as a combination.

Comment: That's not a greedy algorithm, that's an exhaustive search.  A greedy algorithm would be to take the largest value of `a` for which `2a` is less than 25, then the largest value of `b` for which `3b` is less than the remainder, and so on.  Needless to say a greedy algorithm does not work here.

Comment: Thanks.  Mixed up my terminology.